# Same query returns different results when executed in CF and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, coldfusion

I have the following query which returns 1 record when executed in SQL Server:

```
SELECT * from item WHERE lower(_name) like '%icc (initial)%'
```

When I run it in a ColdFusion page, it returns 0 records.

ColdFusion query code:

```
<cfset skipChck = Trim(lcase("ICC (Initial)"))> 
<cfquery name="result" datasource="#application.dsn#">
   SELECT * from item
   WHERE 1=1
   AND   lower(_name) like '%#skipChck#%'
</cfquery>
```

or

```
<cfquery name="result" datasource="#application.dsn#">
    SELECT * from item
    WHERE 1=1
    AND lower(_name) like <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#skipChck#%">
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Please post the *actual* cfquery code.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details. Are you 100% certain you copied and executed the *exact same sql* from the CF debug output? Just to be thorough, try using `select someColumnName ...` instead of `select *` as well. However, there is really no reason that specific query should return different results in CF. It is most likely something else.

Comment: Troubleshooting Step 1 - run the identical query in CF.  That means no query param, no variable, etc.  If that returns a row, add the query parameter, but not the variable.  If that returns a row, it's probably your variable.  If Step 1 does not return a row, make sure your application.dsn variable is pointing to the same database that you tested with SSMS.

Comment: i tried eben the stotd procedure, it does not  work

Comment: Did you review the comments above and try the suggested steps? What were the results?